# Java method changes the variable which was passed to it

Tags: java, arrays, methods, return

I was trying to implement encryption in my program and ran into some difficulties with methods. I have a unencrypted array, which should stay unencrypted and another array which I would like to encrypt. However, when I call the method it encrypts both arrays.

```
import java.util.Base64;

public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] arr = {"1", "2"};
        String[] arrEncrypted = encryption(arr);
        System.out.println(arr[0]);
        System.out.println(arrEncrypted[0]);
    }
    public static String[] encryption(String[]  data) {
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { // get each element of data
            String encodedString = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(data[i].getBytes()); // encryption
            data[i] = encodedString; // reassign
        }
        return data;
    }
}
```

I cannot find out an issue because in my understanding I return encrypted data and assign it to another array, but for some reason an array which I passed changes too.

Here is the output

```
MQ== //has to be 1
MQ== //correct
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you invoke `encryption(arr)` you are passing the value of the *reference* for that object through, which means you end up directly mutating it. If you did not return `data` and declared `encryption` as `void` return, your input array would still be "encrypted."

If you'd like to solely return a new array without modifying the input, you can initialise a new, empty `String[]` of the same length as the input, and assign elements to it in your for loop.

For example,

```java
    public static String[] encryption(String[]  data) {
        String[] encrypted = new String[data.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { // get each element of data
            String encodedString = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(data[i].getBytes()); // encryption
            encrypted[i] = encodedString; // reassign
        }
        return encrypted;
    }
```

Please see [Is Java "pass-by-reference" or "pass-by-value"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value) for a thorough explanation of what's going on under the hood when you pass in your `data` argument.

Answer (score 0):

Three things:

1. You can't "pass a variable", you can only pass the value of a variable.
2. The variable "arr" is not the array, it has a value which is a reference to the array.
3. And therefore the variable "data" gets a copy of the value of "arr", which is a reference to **the same array**.

You should allocate a new array for the output, something like

```
String[] outData = new String[data.length];
```